# second condition in sql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have still problem with create properly my sql syntax.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.sub_menu_id, p.sub_menu_name, m.category_id, m.image_id, p.sub_menu_price, p.status, i.file_url, m.default_menu_id, p.restaurant_id, m.id
               FROM sub_sub_menu AS p
               INNER JOIN menu AS m ON m.id = p.sub_menu_id
               INNER JOIN icon AS i ON i.id = m.image_id
               WHERE p.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' ";
```

There is my code, but I wanna make something like when `m.id = p.sub_menu_id` is not true, use this `m.default_menu_id = p.sub_menu_id`

**Update**

```
"SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.sub_menu_id, p.sub_menu_name, m.category_id, m.image_id, p.sub_menu_price, p.status, i.file_url, m.default_menu_id, p.restaurant_id, m.id
               FROM sub_sub_menu AS p
               INNER JOIN menu AS m ON m.id = p.sub_menu_id
                                    OR m.default_menu_id = p.sub_menu_id
               INNER JOIN icon AS i ON i.id = m.image_id
               WHERE p.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' ";
```

now rows are selected (showed) from `m.default_menu_id = p.sub_menu_id` twice.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is not always easy to penetrate the problem just by looking at one query that operates a dozen columns in three tables. Sometimes you need to provide a data sample and explain what kind of result you would like to get from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN menu AS m 
       ON m.id = p.sub_menu_id
       OR m.default_menu_id = p.sub_menu_id
```

Comment: thanks jurgen but now I have rows from `m.default_menu_id = p.sub_menu_id` showed twice.

Comment: That is because you have probably 2 records that match that criteria in sub_sub_menu. You need another condition to choose the correct ones.

Comment: I have same id and everything...  I don't know why. I need this complex syntax only because I wanna have access to i.file_url (image), id of this row is stored in menu table, and to this menu is paired with product by sub_menu_id